# How to merge two shapefiles using FME?

Tags: fme-form

I have a workflow in FME in which I read some autocad files, do some transformations and output some shape files.
My question is how can I merge the shape files with the same geometry and type of attributes?
Is there a straight forward way to do this through FME?

Comment: This help doc may help: http://docs.safe.com/fme/2014beta/html/FME_Workbench/Default.htm#Merging_Feature_Types.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way is to create a generate a 'dynamic shapefile' reader and writer

This assumes that the shapefiles are one feature type.

File> Generate Workspace
select your shapefiles
workflow options (dynamic)

[image]

Full documentation 
http://docs.safe.com/fme/2014beta/html/FME_Workbench/Default.htm#Filling_in_the_Workspace_Dialog.htm